# search using Notepad Wild card

Tags: text, notepad++

In Notepad++ How can I search using wildcards for

```
taxRate.set_FromDate(this.startDate);
```

and replace with

```
taxRate.FromDate = this.startDate;
```

P.S. I want to use this for a large file.

Comment: Where should wildcards be used?

Comment: If I had to guess, taxRate could have a few different instances with different values or variations of it in the code. Would this be correct? if so where would the wildcard need to be placed?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the other answers address standard find-and-replace functionality, which works the same as any number of other editors, including MS Word.  Using wildcards is a lot less obvious, however.

Let's say that `taxRate` is the variable part of the expression.  After hitting `Ctrl-H` to reach the `Replace` dialog, you could enter the following for `Find what`:

```
(.*)\.set_FromDate\(this\.startDate\);
```

Here's what going on:

- Some characters--a couple periods and the parentheses--need to be interpreted literally by prefixing with a `\`.
- `.*` matches any amount of number of non-new-line characters.  (Note: In general this is the lazy way to match; often it's better to be more precise by specifying the allowed or disallowed characters.)
- The (non-escaped) parentheses around `.*` turn it into a variable.

Under `Replace with`:

```
$1.FromDate = this.startDate;
```

Here `$1` (or `\1`) would substitute the value of the first variable described above.  You could use `$2`, `$3`, etc., as well if you had multiple uses of `()`.

This is all typical regular expression syntax, so any such reference would be relevant for further information.

Answer (score 0):

press

```
control + H
```

then put

```
taxRate.set_FromDate(this.startDate);
```

in "Find what" field, and

```
taxRate.FromDate = this.startDate;
```

in "Replace with" field.

Answer (score -1):

Just do that by search and replace tool.
press `Ctrl+F`key and the search and replace will be apear.
like this image guide:
[image]